# Filling Postmark template from Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, feign, postmark

I need to send an email with the template using Postmark. Instead of using Postmark library, my project uses Feign Client with configured token and url.

However, this approach makes harder to fill the template with data. How to inject data from Spring application into template located at `resources` folder?

Here's my feign client and dto classes:

```
@FeignClient(value = "postmark", url = "${email.postmark-url}", configuration = PostmarkConfig.class)
public interface PostmarkFeignClient {

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
     @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
     PostmarkResponse sendEmailWithTemplate(@RequestBody PostmarkRequest postmarkRequest);
}
```

And here's PostmarkRequest:

```
private String from;
private String to;
private String cc;
private String subject;
private String replyTo;

private String htmlBody;
private String textBody;
private Long templateId;
private Object templateModel;
private String templateAlias;

private boolean inlineCss = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that I need to post a template to Postmark server. After that I can use template id OR alias to use it with my generated email.

```
PostmarkRequest mail = new PostmarkRequest();
mail.setFrom(someSender);
mail.setTo(someRecipient);
//Here I put the alias name
mail.setTemplateAlias("my-alias");
mail.setTemplateModel(someModel);
```